# running python code in an external shell using sublimetext?

Tags: python, shell, sublimetext3

First of all, I am new to programming.
To run python code in an external shell window, I followed the instructions given on this page 
[link](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/build-system-for-python/16118/7)

My problem is that if I save the python file in any path that contains a folder name with a space, it gives me this error:

> C:\Python34\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\Program': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Does not work:

> C:\Program Files\Python Code

Works:

> C:\ProgramFiles\PythonCode

**could someone help me fix the problem???**

Here is the code:

```
    import sublime
import sublime_plugin
import subprocess
class PythonRunCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        command = 'cmd /k "C:\Python34\python.exe" %s' % sublime.active_window().active_view().file_name()
        subprocess.Popen(command)
```

Comment: Try adding quotes in your `command = 'cmd ... "%s"'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subprocess` methods accept a string or a list. Passing as a string is the lazy way: just copy/paste your command line and it works. That is for hardcoded commands, but things get complicated when you introduce parameters known at run-time only, which may contain spaces, etc...

Passing a `list` is better because you don't need to compose your command and escape spaces by yourself. Pass the parameters as a list so it's done automatically and better that you could do:

```
command = ['cmd','/k',r"C:\Python34\python.exe",sublime.active_window().active_view().file_name()]
```

And always use raw strings (`r` prefix) when passing literal windows paths or you may have some surprises with escape sequences meaning something (linefeed, tab, unicode...)

In this particular case, if file associations are properly set, you only need to pass the python script without any other command prefix:

```
command = [sublime.active_window().active_view().file_name()]
```

(you'll need `shell=True` added to the `subprocess` command but it's worth it because it avoids to hardcode python path, and makes your plugin portable)

Comment: are you sure it will work with folders  that have names with space?

Comment: see my edit (first sentence). subprocess accepts both.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are great!